# Java: Rounding UP double value in iterative manner

Tags: java, double, rounding

Let's consider below code snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.00");            
        double k=4.144456;
        System.out.println(twoDForm.format(k));
    }
```

I was expecting output as **4.15** as if we consider iterative rounding, the answer should be **4.15**, but I guess `DecimalFormat` checks only immediate next digit value while rounding.

Is there any way by which I can achieve iterative rounding output.

Comment: Just to check - are you sure you want that behaviour?  4.144456 is close to 4.14 than it is to 4.15, thus the behaviour above *should* be what you want.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I agree with you that 4.14 is nearer than 4.15, but if rounding is performed in iterative manner, then it should be 4.15.

Comment: @SachinMhetre Why do you want an unnecessarily large rounding error?

Comment: I tried to look up "iterative rounding" in the hope of learning its merits and how precisely it is defined. Unfortunately, my searches only hit an optimization technique with the same name. Could you provide a link to a definition and discussion of this meaning of "iterative rounding"?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Because answer given by JDK and calculated on Windows Calculator is much different. I wondered how I am getting different behavior on same machine by different application.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan JDK's answer for 240.0*0.1962*1.666 = 78.44860730409621 where as calculator answer for same is 78.448608.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I don't have any link for same. But what I mean is 4.144456 will be rounded to 4.14446 which will further rounded to 4.1445 and so on till I get 2 decimal answer i.e. 4.15. I hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: I have done the calculation 240.0*0.1962*1.666 in Java double arithmetic. I get exact value 78.4486079999999930123522062785923480987548828125, which default rounds to 78.448608. I don't think the difference is in output rounding.

Comment: I suggest writing a new question in which you show your exact code and ask why it is not getting the answer you expect.

Comment: I don't think the OP needs special rounding. It seems to be a problem in calculating the double value. However, I have provided an answer to the special rounding question to avoid leaving it unanswered.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, Thanks for all the details you have provided. The issue was with data type I had used. Type **double**, was causing decimal point issue. To handle this I changed data type of all the variable to  **BigDecimal** and problem solved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question calls for a unique rounding mode. This answer addresses the general issue of getting special rounding.

The `BigDecimal(double)` constructor and BigDecimal's `toString()` method are both exact.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
String s = bd.toString();
```

leaves `s` with an exact, unrounded, `String` representation of `double` `d`. You can then do any required string manipulation to get the value you want. In addition, you can use any of the `BigDecimal` rounding modes in rounding `bd`.